# Formtastic custom required fields translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, formtastic

I'm trying to add some custom translations to required fields using [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)

[image]

My actually code looks like:

```
pt-BR:
  formtastic:
    required: "Obrigatório"
```

So I want that a determinate field have a different translation of each other, is that possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you asking if you can code in more than one translation for a label?

Comment: No, I just wanna that each label have a different translation